# Rebinning ndarray while conserving summation

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing

I am looking for some function that can be used to rebin some `ndarray`, that satisfies:

1. The result can be arbitrary dimensions, either upscaling or downscaling.
2. After the rebinning, the summation should be the same as before.
3. It should not change the overall image shape. In other words, it should be reversible in case of upscaling.

Second constraint is not just summation-normalization or something, but the rebinning algorithm itself should calculate the fraction the original array elements are overlapped within resulting array elements.

Third argument can be tested in this way:

```py
# image is ndarray with shape of 20x20
func(image, func(image, [40,40]),[20,20])==image # if func works as intended
```

So far I am aware of only two functions, which are

- `ndarray.resize`: I don't fully understand what it does, but basically not what I am looking for.
- `scipy.misc.imresize`: It interpolates values of each element, which is not so good for my purpose.

But they does not satisfy conditions I mentioned. As an example, I attached a code to argue the behaviour of `scipy.misc.imresize`.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import erf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.misc import imresize

def gaussian(size, center, width, a):
    xcoord=np.arange(size[0])[:,np.newaxis]+np.zeros(size[1])[np.newaxis,:]
    ycoord=np.zeros(size[0])[:,np.newaxis]+np.arange(size[1])[np.newaxis,:]
    return a*((erf((xcoord+1-center[0])/(width[0]*np.sqrt(2)))-erf((xcoord-center[0])/(width[0]*np.sqrt(2))))*
              (erf((ycoord+1-center[1])/(width[1]*np.sqrt(2)))-erf((ycoord-center[1])/(width[1]*np.sqrt(2)))))

size=np.asarray([20,20])
c=[[0.1,0.2],[0.4,0.6],[0.8,0.4]]
c=[np.asarray(x) for x in c]
s=[[0.02,0.02],[0.05,0.05],[0.03,0.01]]
s=[np.asarray(x) for x in s]
im = gaussian(size, c[0]*size, s[0]*size, 1) \
    +gaussian(size, c[1]*size, s[1]*size, 3) \
    +gaussian(size, c[2]*size, s[2]*size, 2)
sciim=imresize(imresize(im,[40,40]),[20,20])
plt.imshow(im/np.sum(im)-sciim/np.sum(sciim))
plt.show()
```

So, is there any function, preferably built-in function to some package, that satisfies my requirements?

For other language, I know that [`frebin`](https://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/ftp/pro/image/frebin.pro) in IDL works as what I mentioned. Of course I could re-write the function, or perhaps someone already did it, but I wonder whether if there is any existing solution.

Comment: `func(image, func(image, [40,40]),[20,20])==image` will almost never be `True` due to rounding and/or floating-point errors.  Using `lanczos` kernel and `mode = "F"` will improve your `imsize` results for reversing the interpolation.

Comment: Wait, the reason `frebin` looks so good on your toy problem is that it duplicates pixels when the size changes by an integer ratio.  You can do the same in your code by making your kernel `nearest` - which will make the differences on the order of `10**-9` in your toy problem but won't work well otherwise.

Comment: I didn't know about the integral ratio part of `frebin`. Thank you. But the point still stands. `imresize` with `interp='lanczos' ` and `mode="F"` still yields error as large as 0.3%, which is in my belief much larger than arithmetic erorrs.

Comment: What does `frebin` give you for error when you expand by a non-integer ratio?  I'd imagine it's worse, since it appears to be doing simple linear interpolation.

Comment: Ok. I did calculated for 30,30 and the error from `frebin` is actually 3 times larger than your answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`frebin` implements pixel duplication when the expansion is by integer value (like the 2x increase in your toy problem).  If you want similar reversibility in such cases, try this:

```
def py_frebin(im, shape):
    if np.isclose(x.shape % shape , np.zeros.like(x.shape)):
        interp = 'nearest'
    else:
        interp = 'lanczos'
    im2 = scipy.misc.imresize(im, shape, interp = interp, mode = 'F')
    im2 *= im.sum() / im2.sum()
    return im2
```

Should be better than `frebin` in non-integer expansions (as `frebin` seems to be doing `interp = 'bilinear'` which is less reversible), and similar in integral expansions.